# Java RegEx find, except when between quotes

Tags: java, regex, split, quotes

I need a Java RegEx to split, or find something in a string, but exclude stuff that's between double quotes. What I do now is this:

```
String withoutQuotes = str.replaceAll("\\\".*?\\\"", "placeholder");
withoutQuotes = withoutQuotes.replaceAll(" ","");
```

but this doesn't work nice with indexOf, and I also need to be able to split, for example:

```
String str = "hello;world;how;\"are;you?\""
String[] strArray = str.split(/*some regex*/);
// strArray now contains: ["hello", "world", "how", "\"are you?\"]
```

- quotes are always balanced
- quotes can be escaped with `\"`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are quotes always balanced? And can these quotes be escaped using `\"`

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to mention. Yes, quotes are balanced, and yes, they can be escaped with \"

Comment: What do you mean the first thing doesn't work nice with indexOf?

Comment: if you save the index, and then use it on the original string, it won't be the same char, because the placeholder will probably have a different length from the original quoted text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok here is a code that will work for you:

```
String str = "a \"hello world;\";b \"hi there!\"";
String[] arr = str.split(";(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

This regex find a semi-colon if it is followed by even number of double quotes (which means `;` is outside quotes).

**OUTPUT:**

```
[a "hello world;", b "hi there!"]
```

**PS:** It doesn't take care of escaped quotes like `\"`

Comment: It works almost perfectly, but when I try this: `a "hello world;";
b "hi there!";`, it returns `["a "hello world"",""","b "hi there""]`

Comment: Can you give me a valid Java String value that I can try.

Comment: Here you go: `a \"hello world;\";b \"hi there!\"`

Comment: see updated answer though `It doesn't take care of escaped quotes like \"`

Comment: is there an easy way to add that? otherwhise I'll think of some other way to accomplish that

Comment: That's what I tried but it broke this simple case as well. I believe doing all that via regex will immensely difficult.

Comment: OK, then I'll think up something else. Thank you for your time again

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting this question because it had a simple regex solution that wasn't mentioned. (Found your question while doing some research for a [regex bounty quest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174).)

```
\"[^\"]*\"|(;)
```

The left side of the alternation matches complete quoted strings. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures semi-colons to Group 1, and we know they are the right semi-colons because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

Here is working code (see [online demo](http://ideone.com/C0hNwd)):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.List;

class Program {
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {

String subject = "hello;world;how;\"are;you?\"";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|(;)");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(subject);
StringBuffer b= new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if(m.group(1) != null) m.appendReplacement(b, "SplitHere");
    else m.appendReplacement(b, m.group(0));
}
m.appendTail(b);
String replaced = b.toString();
String[] splits = replaced.split("SplitHere");
for (String split : splits) System.out.println(split);
} // end main
} // end Program
```

**Reference**

1. [How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
2. [How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)